# Countability of $E_1 \times E_2 \times ...$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

True or False: If $E_1, E_2,...$ are finite sets and $$E:= E_1 \times E_2 \times ...\,\, := \left\{(x_1,x_2...): x_j \in E_j\,\,\forall j \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$ then $E$ is countable.

Attempt:  Each $E_j$ is finite so there exists a $1-1$ function taking $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow  E_j$.  Hence each $E_j$ is at most countable.  This means that for any two of the $E_j$, $E_i \times E_j$ is also countable.  The Cartesian Product of infinitely many $E_j$ can be counted in a similar way to Cantor's Diagonal Argument. So I conclude that the statement is True.  Yet in my answer scheme, it says False.

Can someone clarify my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Cantor's [diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) shows that infinite products **are not** countable!

Comment: So I have the right reasoning but made the wrong conclusion simply?

Comment: If $E_i$ is finite then there is **no** injection from $\Bbb N$ into $E_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{0,1\}=E_1=E_2=\cdots$ Then $E$ is simply the set of all sequences of zeros and ones. Suppose the set were countable and $e_1,e_2,e_3,\ldots$ an enumeration. Then the sequence $(d_n)$ given by $d_n=1-e_n(n)$ differs from each element in the sequence $e_1,e_2,e_3,\ldots$. So $E$ can't be countable. This is simply the Cantor diagonal argument.

Comment: When I said Cantor's diagonal argument, I meant the 'array' method used to show that the rationals are countable.  What is the mistake in my answer?

Comment: @CAF "The Cartesian Product of infinitely many $E_j$ can be counted in a similar way to Cantor's Diagonal Argument." is simply not true. Try to write out what "similar way" is supposed to mean. Btw: There is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $E_j$, but no 1-1-function.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I reliased that.  What I meant to say was they can be counted via the same way as was used to show that the rationals are countable (e.g using arrows in a grid like structure).  Doesn't a finite set $E$ imply there exists a function from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow E$?

Comment: @CAF What you wrote can be done in a similar way cannot be done. If you try to fill in the details, you will see that. There is always a functionf from $\mathbb{N}$ to a finite nonempty set. But a 1-1-function maps different elements to different elements, and this would require the function to take on infinitely many values.

Comment: I see. It makes sense.  How does it conform with my defintion in my book:  Let $E$ be a set.  $E$ is said to be finite if and only if either $E = \emptyset$ or there exists a $1-1$ function which takes $\left\{1,2,...n\right\}$ onto $E$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Is it because here we restict $n$ to some value within $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @CAF Exactly. If you do not restrict the set, you have to map lots of numbers to the same element.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  In your answer, what are the $e_i$?

Comment: @CAF They are the elements of $E$. I assume he elements in $E$ can be ordered in asequence (so they are countable) and then show that I can fin an element not in this sequence. This contradiction proves that $E$ is not countable.

Comment: That is what I thought but then how does $1-e_i$ make sense?  (Since an element of $E$ is of the form $(x_1,x_2...)$ where each $x_i = 0,1$.  Thanks.

Comment: @CAF You are right, it should be $d_n=1-e_n(n)$. I've changed it.